# How to initialise a VC or Class iOS, ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, uitabview

When a button is clicked at `FirstVC`, it will pass data and trigger `SecondVC` using NSNotificationCenter

During initial launch of the app, because `SecondVC` has not been initialize yet, so data cannot be passed to `SecondVC`. `NSNotificationCenter` cannot function properly. Only after `SecondVC` has been initialize, `NSNotificationCenter` will function correctly.

So I need to initialise `SecondVC` somewhere. Will it be at `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`?

Or how do I programatically call the tab of `SecondVC`.

## FirstVC

```
#import "Search.h"

#import "Classes.h"
#import "MyTabBarController.h"

@interface Search(){

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    CERangeSlider* _rangeSlider;
    NSString *sURL, *strResult, *sRemaining, *sStartTime, *sEndTime,     *sSelectedLat, *sSelectedLong;
}

@end

@implementation Search

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (IBAction)btnSearch:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

    sURL = @"Testing 123";

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sURL forKey:@"theURL"];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"toClasses" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

}

@end
```

## Second VC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
 name:@"toClasses"
 object:nil];

    dtDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //=== Mutable array to store the dates generated
    self.currentPageIndex = 0;

    [self setupSegmentButtons];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
    sDtDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

    [self LoadClasses];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //--- Hide the Top Navigation Controller Bar at the current View
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

}

//--- Top Navigation Controller reappear on the next VC
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

-(void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"toClasses"])
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSLog (@"Successfully received userInfo! %@", userInfo);
        NSString* sFromSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", userInfo];
        NSLog (@"Successfully received test notification! %@", sFromSearch);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in this case, after you set `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1`, `SecondViewController` is initialized. Can you check it again? `postNotificationName` or `viewDidLoad` from `SecondViewController` is called first?

Comment: You added observer in viewDidLoad, so it will not work even you create it before user tap on button and send notification. because observer will not be registered. I advise you not use observer to send data in this case. you can save this data elsewhere and use it when seconVC will load. for example in singleton object.

Comment: Jabson, I think NSNotificationCenter is not a good way to pass data to different VC. Can you elaborate singleton object please

Comment: Ok, i will write as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to use notification or singleton on this case.

Simply, get `SecondViewController` from `self.tabBarController` and call the method.

## First VC

```
- (IBAction)btnSearch:(UIButton *)sender {
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

  sURL = @"Testing 123";

  UINavigationController* secondNav = (UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
  SecondViewController* secondViewController = [secondNav.viewControllers firstObject];

  [secondViewController handleString:sURL];
}
```

## Second VC

```
- (void)handleString:(NSString*)string {
  // Do whatever you want with string passed from First VC
}
```

Comment: Hi I can't get it to work, I got the following error 
`SFITNESS[48757:4308777] -[ClassNavigationController handleString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd9b883b400
2018-04-19 11:42:48.688521+0800 SFITNESS[48757:4308777] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClassNavigationController handleString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd9b883b400'`

Comment: Seem like you embed `SecondViewController` in an `UINavigationController`. I have updated my answer, you can check it again.

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You added observer in viewDidLoad, so it will not work even you create it before user tap on button and send notification. because observer will not be registered. I advise you not use observer to send data in this case. you can save this data elsewhere and use it when seconVC will load. for example in singleton object.

your Singleton object looks like this:

Interface:

```
@interface DataManager : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *userInfo;
+ (DataManager *) getInstance;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation DataManager

+ (DataManager *) getInstance {
    static DataManager *appManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        appManager = [[DataManager alloc] init];
    });

    return appManager;
}

@end
```

Now you can access this object where you want and you can assured that only one instance is created.

here is your button click method:

```
- (IBAction)btnSearch:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
    sURL = @"Testing 123";
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sURL forKey:@"theURL"];
    [DataManager getInstance].userInfo = userInfo;
}
```

and your viewDidLoad in secondVC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [DataManager getInstance].userInfo;
}
```